# Image Uploading in Meteor , uploading empty files

Tags: node.js, meteor, fs

I am working on meteor framework and trying to upload images in one of my app using the code from the link

https://gist.github.com/3922137

Everything works good , except that it uploads the empty file in my public folder of app .

I checked console and it shows 503 error there after I select a file to upload

Here is the console screenshot
http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/2956/consolewl.jpg

It keeps on looping and  the number of errors keeps on adding in console

I am using meteor on windows .

Does anyone has managed to get file uploads work in meteor on windows platform ? and if yes can you please share the code which worked for you .

Thanks
Aman

Comment: what is the err_log in your meteor console?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a 503 is that when anything in the public folder changes meteor reloads. Because your uploads are going there the server is resetting. Change your code not to save it to public but rather somewhere else and you should see the error go away.